# predicate serialization

Tags: .net, serialization, predicate, jint

Let's say that I have a bit of .NET code...

```
public class EventEnvelope
{
  public Dictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; }
  public byte[] Body { get; set; }
}

public class EventSelector
{
  public Predicate<Dictionary<string, string>> Selector { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to send this event selector to an event broker NOT written in .NET.

How might I serialize this predicate in a cross-platform way such that a program written in another language could reconstruct the predicate and execute it?

I had thought of trying to write a serializer that would write out the predicate as a bit of javascript and then either have rhino or jint interpret and execute it at the broker.

Or perhaps there's an actual cross-platform way of representing predicates that I'm unaware of?

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define your predicate as an [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx), and then trying to serialize the expression tree? That way you can get a consistent way for serializing your predicates and executing them.

Comment: That might work for .NET, but I'm not sure how I would deserialize the expression tree in java, let alone execute it.  Make sense?